# Text align not working under div using javascript print button

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have placed a div on html page and text under it with center align. A custom java script button is also placed for printing under the div content. When i press a button it previews the text with left align. Please anyone guide how to set or apply my css or style to this div for center align. Complete html code is following written in asp.net. Thanks in advance

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="margin_issue.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <title></title>

</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1">

         <div id="DivForPrint" class="myDivToPrint" style="border: 1px dotted black; text-align: right; padding-left: 250px; width: 600px">
            <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial">Hello,
            <br />
                This is <span style="color: #0090CB">Mudassar Khan</span>.<br />
                Hoping that you are enjoying my articles!</span>
        </div>
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="Print" onclick="javascript: printDiv('DivForPrint')" style="width: 80px; height: 30px;" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function printDiv(divID) {
        //Get the HTML of div
        var divElements = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;
        //Get the HTML of whole page
        var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;

        //Reset the page's HTML with div's HTML only
        document.body.innerHTML =
          "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" +
          divElements + "</body>";

        //Print Page
        window.print();

        //Restore orignal HTML
        document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;
    }
</script>
```

**EDIT**

Your code is working awesome according to my need. I have little observations that i need to understand. I have copied two portions from your code, CSS and javascript. Please see below.

```
<style>
        .page_size { border: 1px dotted black;  text-align: left; width: 800px; height: 950px; }
        .instr_date { text-align: right; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 40px;}
        .benef_name {text-align: left; padding-left: 50px;  padding-top: 50px; }
        .leftDiv { border: 1px dotted black; text-align: left; padding-left: 0px;     }
    </style>
```

Javascript

```
    function printDiv(divID) {

        var div = document.getElementById(divID).outerHTML;
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'Print Contents');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print Contents</title>');

        mywindow.document.write('<style>  .page_size {border: 1px dotted black; text-align: left; width: 800px; height: 950px; }</style>');
        mywindow.document.write('<style> .instr_date {text-align: right; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 40px;        }</style>');
        mywindow.document.write('<style> .benef_name { text-align: left; padding-left: 50px; padding-top: 50px; }</style>');
        mywindow.document.write('<style> .leftDiv {border: 1px dotted black; text-align: left; padding-left: 0px; }</style>');

        mywindow.document.write('</head><body>');
        mywindow.document.write(div);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        mywindow.document.close();  // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.focus();           // necessary for IE >= 10

        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();
    }

</script>
```

You can see above i have written two css files, one is normal under style tag and other is injected to java script *and i am writing many lines for css in java script*.  Now i have two simple questions following:-

1- Cannot we write one css which should effect everywhere?.

2- If the answer of first question is no: then how can i avoid writing multiple css lines in java script.

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you want the style for printing to be different from the style already displayed?

Comment: Yes, i want to properly align the text, left, center right whatever according to my css, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following to point you in the right direction. Instead of changing the entire page and then reverting it, open a new `window` to do the print. This will stop any potentially nasty bugs appearing when revert the page. Also having 2 different `class names` for non-print and print `DIVs` may be useful. You can put these in an external `CSS` file and then add the `CSS` link to the new window aswell.

---

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">

      <title>
      </title>

      <style>
        .myDiv {
          border: 1px dotted black; text-align: right; padding-left: 250px; width: 600px;
        }
      </style>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        function printDiv(divID) {

          var div = document.getElementById(divID).outerHTML;
          var mywindow = window.open('', 'Print Contents');
          mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print Contents</title>');
          mywindow.document.write('<style>.myDiv {border: 1px dotted black; text-align: center; width: 100%;}</style>');
          mywindow.document.write('</head><body>');
          mywindow.document.write(div);
          mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

          mywindow.document.close();  // necessary for IE >= 10
          mywindow.focus();           // necessary for IE >= 10

          mywindow.print();
          mywindow.close();
        }
      </script>

  </head>
  <body>

      <form id="form1">
           <div id="DivForPrint" class="myDiv">
              <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial">Hello,
              <br />
              This is <span style="color: #0090CB">Mudassar Khan</span>.<br />
              Hoping that you are enjoying my articles!</span>
          </div>
          <br />
          <input type="button" value="Print" onclick="javascript: printDiv('DivForPrint')" style="width: 80px; height: 30px;" />
      </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code is working awesome. I have two simple questions  that i have explained in EDIT portion in my original question, Please look into it, Many thanks.

Comment: Yep, really simple. Just add an external CSS file and put your styles in there. Then link it on your HTML and the JS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have used this code but its not working                                                      '                                                  "document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Content/styles_print.css" />')"           Please guide.

Comment: No problem, can you mark as correct? The code is valid so the href must be wrong

Comment: Thanks for the help :);